# Change input text via chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm making a chrome extension, and I made a context menu option.

I want to get the focused input field and change it's text.

That's what I have so far:

```
function click()
{
    var $focused = $(':focus');
    $focused.val("test");

}
chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "Paste", "contexts":["editable"], "onclick" : click});
```

But it doesn't change the input field's text, what do I need?

I added an `alert("test");` to the `click()` function and it worked.

Comment: Is jQuery included? Are you getting errors in your `console` window?

Comment: No, and I have included jQuery. It's just not writing to the page. Apparently it's not taking the current page elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that focus is simply being stolen by the plugin button you click :)

Can you try setting a specific field value, using an ID or name select, to check your DOM access? Once you confirm that I suggest you use another event such as

```
$(document).on('focus', 'input', function(e){
    // set field here
    $(this).val("test");
});
```

to catch focus changes.